# gtag function Typescript definition

Tags: typescript, gtag.js

I use original Javascript function

```
function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
```

then got error: `error TS2554: Expected 0 arguments, but got 3.` when used like this:

`gtag('event', 'page_view', { send_to: 'xxxx' })`
I used `// @ts-ignore` as a workaround and it works: I see traffic in Google analytics. I want to do it properly without workarounds and I tried to replace gtag function like this:

```
function gtag(...args: any) {
  window.dataLayer.push(args)
}
```

and some other variants but it did not work. I see that `window.dataLayer` items now contain `array` instead of `Object` or `Arguments`.

Or better is there some existing gtag wrapper something similar to [react-gtm](https://github.com/alinemorelli/react-gtm) or [react-ga](https://github.com/react-ga/react-ga) but for [gtagjs](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs)?

Comment: `window.dataLayer.push.apply(window.dataLayer, args)` might work as a hack but I would recommend looking for TS type definitions to use instead

Answer (score 81, accepted):

You can install `@types/gtag.js`. See https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/4d4da2106dcd54af4a0ddeb5e0360f322fd8a5bf/types/gtag.js

`yarn add -D @types/gtag.js`

or

`npm install --save-dev @types/gtag.js`

Depending on your `tsconfig`, you might need to add it to the [`types`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#types) option.

Comment: It's a shame that package is missing an example of how to use it.
I had an hour or so of trail and error to axe the TS errors, until landing on this line `const gtag: Gtag.Gtag = function () {window.dataLayer.push(arguments);};`

Comment: Super ! It sad that the "consent" part is missing.

Comment: I got the types to work with the command `declare var gtag: Gtag.Gtag;` after restarting Visual Studio Code.

Comment: For consent, simply force you GA ID that's probably coming from an env variable to be a string `ID = process.env.ID as string`

Comment: import it like this in Angular `import "node_modules/@types/gtag.js/index.d.ts";`

Answer (score 18):

To expand on the answer by @thisismydesign.

Install:

```sh
yarn add -D @types/gtag.js
```

And it should detect it globally automatically. But if `types` is set in `tsconfig.json`, it probably won't. Either remove `types` from the config or add `@types/gtag.js` to it like so:

```
"types": ["cypress", "@testing-library/cypress", "@types/gtag.js"],
```

Also note that if this is added then any build directory may need deleting to stop things like linting from hanging.

Answer (score 4):

To get my code to compile it required one more step than above..

```
    npm install --save-dev @types/gtag.js
```

Add to types in tsconfig.json

```
    "types": [..., "@types/gtag.js", ...]
```

Declare the function in the files that you want to use it

```
    declare let gtag: Function;
```

Comment: why "declare let gtag: Function;" it should come from type file right

Answer (score 0):

In case you have `"node_modules/@types"` in your typeRoots like this:

```
"typeRoots": [
    ...,
    "node_modules/@types",
    ...
]
```

you need to add `@types/gtag.js` to your types without the `@types/`-Folder like this:

```
"types": [
    ...,
    "gtag.js",
    ...
]
```

This was necessary in order for ts to find the definitions