# Typescript: Add typing to function that uses "arguments" keyword

Tags: typescript

is there a way to add typing information to this function? More specifically how do you add type information to `arguments`?

```js
function gtag() {
  dataLayer.push(arguments);
}
```

Of course the error you get is `Expected 0 arguments, but got 2.` when trying to call e.g. `gtag(1, 2)`. This code snippet comes from google analytics.
Thanks

Comment: Look at [the arguments object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) and [IArguments](http://jbeard4.github.io/SCION-CORE/interfaces/__nvm_versions_v8_4_0_lib_node_modules_typedoc_node_modules_typescript_lib_lib_es5_d_.iarguments.html). The arguments object is basically an indexed object, so it doesn't hold any type information. In your sample code, it would be impossible for typescript to make sure `arguments` is properly typed.

Comment: So it seems `arguments` cannot be used in typescript, this is odd since TS is supposedly a superset of JS. Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29918324/is-typescript-really-a-superset-of-javascript

Comment: [Of course you can use it](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAEzgZTgWwKZQBYxgDmAFAHQUCGATkQM4BcilYAngNoC6AlEwG5wYyRAG8AsAChE0xBAR04AG2xlFcUjSIgcYKHW4BuSQF9Jk1Bhz5CpAIwAaAEz2AzPYAs9gKyGgA)

Comment: Except you get an error :D

Answer (score 0):

[This SO questions might have the answer for your case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62306920/gtag-function-typescript-definition?rq=1), however for our tsconfig / eslint settings this is something that allowed compilation:

```js
// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars
function gtag(..._args: any[]) {
  // eslint-disable-next-line prefer-rest-params
  dataLayer.push(arguments)
}
```

Note the underscore in `_args`. As to answer the question itself it seems that what @mike-s said is true and you cannot add type information to `arguments`.